# Is it possible to chain relative MX records?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, alias

I need to make an "MX chain" as the following:

```
@alias.mydomain.net --> @mail.mydomain.net --> @smtp.targetdomain.net
         (1)                     (2)                      (3)
```

- Say an SMTP server exists at `smtp.targetdomain.net`:

  ```
  $ host smtp.targetdomain.net
  smtp.targetdomain.net has address 1.2.3.4
  ```
- Say my own domain name is `mydomain.net`. Currently, the jump between
  `(2)` and `(3)` works with the following configuration:

  ```
  mail 10800 IN MX 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
  ```

  Let's check it:

  ```
  $ host mail.mydomain.net
  mail.mydomain.net mail is handled by 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
  ```

  An email sent to foo@mail.mydomain.net is received.
- But the jump between `(1)` and `(2)` doesn't work with the following
  configuration:

  ```
  alias 10800 IN MX 1 mail
  mail 10800 IN MX 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
  ```

  Let's check it:

  ```
  $ host alias.mydomain.net
  alias.mydomain.net mail is handled by 1 mail.mydomain.net.
  ```

  An email sent to foo@alias.mydomain.net is **not** received, and a delivery failure mail is sent back to the sender:

  > < #5.0.0 smtp; 5.1.2 - Bad destination host "DNS Hard Error looking up alias.mydomain.net (MX): all A records of the domain's MX records are invalid" (delivery attempts: 0)> #SMTP#

Is it possible to make such an MX record chain? Do I need to use the following configuration instead?

```
alias 10800 IN MX 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
mail 10800 IN MX 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. An MX entry **must** point to a host with an A record that actually handles mail.  There will be no further lookups to check if the target of an MX record has  an MX of itself.

You need to set

```
alias 10800 IN MX 1 smtp.targetdomain.net.
```

just like with `mail`.

However, you can have MX records for all records in a domain and don't need to create one for every A record, so I don't see what you want to achieve anyway.

Comment: to clarify an MX entry can point to a CNAME entry right?

Comment: @Matt No, it can't.  It must be an A record.